# selecting the earliest entry in a list

Tags: python, list, sorting

If I have a list with people's names and dates, and I want only to keep the entry for the earliest date per person how do I do that?  I want the final list to be alphabetical by last name, then first name and only contain the entry with the earliest date at the end.

Here is an example of the list and what I tried, but it just gave me back the same list again.

```
L1=['Smith, John, 1994', 'Smith, John, 1996', 'Smith, John, 1998', 'Smith, Joan, 1993', 'Smith, Joan, 1995', 'Smith, Jack, 1989', 'Smith, Jack, 1991', 'Jones, Adam, 2000', 'Jones, Adam, 1998', 'Jones, Sarah, 2002', 'Jones, Sarah, 2005', 'Brady, Tom, 2001', 'Brady, Tonya, 2002']

L1.sort()

L2= []

for item in L1:
    if item.split(',')[:2] not in L2:
        L2.append(item)
```

The final product should look like:

```
L2=['Brady, Tom, 2001', 'Brady, Tonya, 2002', 'Jones, Adam, 1998', 'Jones, Sarah, 2002', 'Smith, Jack, 1989', 'Smith, Joan, 1993', 'Smith, John, 1994']
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
L1.sort()
[next(j) for i, j in itertools.groupby(L1, lambda x: x.rsplit(",", 1)[0])]
```

Your code does not work since you are searching `L2` for `item.split(',')[:2]`, which is only the name.  But the strings in the list consist of the name and the year -- that's why the `not in` always yields `True`.

Comment: just add `sorted()` around and it will be perfect

Comment: @marsx: Did not explicitly say so, but you should `import itertools` then :)

Comment: what does the :) do/where does it go? now it is telling me name 'next' is not defined.

Comment: @marsx: this is not even funny any more. What version of python are you using?

Comment: The :) is just telling you I'm friendly :)  And you can use `j.next()` instead of `next(j)` for Python versions older than 2.6.

Comment: I'm using version 2.5 for Mac.  I am a beginner so I don't know everything yet.

Comment: @marsx: It's perfectly fine to ask questions -- this is what this site is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [next(j) for i, j in groupby(sorted(L1), lambda x: x.rpartition(",")[0])] == L2
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's built in list and tuple sorts are recursive. If your data was stored like so:

```
L1=[(1,2,3),
    (2,3,4),
    (1,1,3)]
```

It would sort your list by the first item in each tuple, then sort each group by the second item, and so on. The result being:

```
[(1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)]
```

So if you break your strings into tuples of `(Date, Last, First)` and then sort you will get the order you desire, but then you'll have to stitch your string back together.

Comment: That's not what recursive sorting means. And how exactly is it related to this question? OP's using 4-digit years, they'll sort just fine within a string.