# selecting the earliest entry in a list that also satisfies other criteria

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Say I have a list `L1`, and the entries in `L1` have 4 parts and are formatted like this `cat1, cat2, date, ID`.  The list is sorted, so alphabetically by the `cat1` entries, then alphabetically by the `cat2` entries, then by the earliest `date`.  I want a subset of this list that contains the entry with earliest date for each `cat1, cat2` pair.  This is the code that I have that does this already:

```
L1=[A, X, 2008-06-01, 1858
A, X, 2008-12-05, 1905
B, X, 2001-08-08, 1149
B, Y, 2006-03-05, 1638
B, Y, 2009-06-09, 1950
C, X, 2005-12-01, 1611
C, X, 2006-08-08, 1689
C, X, 2006-11-22, 1712
C, X, 2008-04-22, 1842
C, Y, 2008-12-05, 1816
C, Y, 2008-12-05, 1821
C, Y, 2008-12-05, 1882
C, Z, 2008-12-05, 1905
C, Z, 2009-06-01, 1935
C, Z, 2009-06-09, 1950
D, X, 2009-11-06, 1989
D, Y, 2008-12-05, 1905
D, Z, 2008-12-05, 1905
D, Z, 2008-12-05, 1905
E, X, 2008-12-05, 1905
E, Z, 2008-12-05, 1905
F, Y, 2008-12-05, 1905
G, X, 2008-12-05, 1905
G, Z, 2007-12-01, 1807]

L2=[j.next() for i, j in itertools.groupby(L1, lambda x: x.split(",", 2)[:2])]

L2=[A, X, 2008-06-01, 1858
B, X, 2001-08-08, 1149
B, Y, 2006-03-05, 1638
C, X, 2005-12-01, 1611
C, Y, 2008-12-05, 1816
C, Z, 2008-12-05, 1905
D, X, 2009-11-06, 1989
D, Y, 2008-12-05, 1905
D, Z, 2008-12-05, 1905
E, X, 2008-12-05, 1905
E, Z, 2008-12-05, 1905
F, Y, 2008-12-05, 1905
G, X, 2008-12-05, 1905
G, Z, 2007-12-01, 1807]
```

The trick now is that I want the earliest entry for each `cat1, cat2` pair where the `ID` is in a list of values in <=3 keys in `dict1` AND `dict2`.  In other words, once the earliest entry for the `cat1, cat2` pair is found is should be tested in each `dict1` and `dict2` and if the `ID` is found to be contained in the value list for 4+ keys of either dictionary, it should go to the next earliest entry for that `cat1, cat2` pair, and in order to add the entry to `L2` its `ID` should be in 3 or less keys in both `dict1` and `dict2`.  I'm not quite sure how to go about this... maybe use re.search or something?

```
dict1[key]=[ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID]    
dict2[key]=[ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID,ID]
```

so instead of L2 having just the earliest entry per `cat1, cat2` pair, it will contain the earliest entry where the `ID` from that entry is not among the `ID` list in 4+ keys in both `dict1` AND `dict2`.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. Could you post some example data please?

Comment: This is a follow-up to [an earlier question asked by marsx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794850/selecting-the-earliest-entry-in-a-list).

Comment: This sounds like a trivial job for a database. Why not use one?

Answer (score 1):

If `dict1` and `dict2`'s value-lists are not too big, you could generate the set of all valid IDs first, then filter L1 to contain only those tuples (X,Y,date,ID) whose IDs are in the set of value IDs:

```
import collections
def valid_ids(*dcts):
    valid=collections.defaultdict(int)
    for dct in dcts:
        for key,value in dct.iteritems():
            valid[value]+=1
    return set(value for value,count in valid.iteritems() if count<=3)

ids=valid_ids(dict1,dict2)

L1_filtered=[text.split(',') for text in L1 if text.split(',')[-1].strip() in ids]
L2 = [j.next() for i, j in itertools.groupby(L1_filtered, lambda x: x.split(",", 2)[:2])]
```

Note that if `dict1` and `dict2` have value-lists with a huge number of IDs, then the above method is not ideal, because you will waste a lot of time determining the set of value ids while in forming `L2` you may only need a little bit of this data.

---

Using [Hugh Bothwell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971729/selecting-the-earliest-entry-in-a-list-that-also-satisfies-other-criteria/4971886#4971886)'s idea, if `dict1` and `dict2` have large value-lists, then it might pay to just check if particular IDs are valid as needed :

```
def is_valid(ID,*dcts):    
    return sum(1 for dct in dcts
               for key,value in dct.iteritems()
               if ID in value) <= 3       

L2=[]
for key, group in itertools.groupby(L1, lambda x: x.split(",", 2)[:2]):
    for text in group:
        X,Y,date,ID = text.split(',')
        X = X.strip()
        Y = Y.strip()
        date = date.strip()
        ID = ID.strip()
        if is_valid(ID,dict1,dict2):
            L2.append(X,Y,date,ID)
            break
    else:
        # There is no valid ID for this group!
        continue
```

---

Note that if you use the first method, with `valid_ids`, you loop through the dicts just once. If you use the second method, you loop through the dicts at least once for every group (unique `X` and `Y` pairs), and possibly multiple times for each group.

My guess is that the first method will be faster for most data sets, but profiling both methods with your real data is probably the safest way to tell.

Comment: what do the *dcts and dct in the function mean? do I have to change anything to make it work in my code?

Comment: The `*dcts` in `valid_ids(*dcts)` allows the function `valid_ids` to take an arbitrary number of arguments. For example, you could call it with just one dict: `valid_ids(dict1)`, or many dicts: `valid_ids(dict1,dict2,dict3)`. However many arguments you pass to `valid_ids`, all the arguments are collected together in one list `dcts`. So inside the function, `for dct in dcts` loops over all the arguments passed to `valid_ids`. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists.

Comment: Barring a programming error on my part, the code is intended to work unchanged.

Comment: okay, also under else, if i just put continue instead of the value error would that just skip the instances where an ID that meets the criteria doesn't exist?

Comment: Indeed, yes. `continue` would just skip to the next group.

Comment: @unutbu I just tried it and for `for X,Y,date,ID in group:` i got a value error saying too many values to unpack. do you know how i could fix that?

Comment: @marsx: Could you add a `print(group)` before that line, and post the output? I must be misunderstanding what is in `group`.

Comment: @unutbu `<itertools._grouper object at 0x18fb750>
<itertools._grouper object at 0x18fbe50>` prints multiple times when i add the print statement

Comment: @marsx: My mistake. Please change that to `print(list(group))` and try again.

Comment: @marsx: Since the print statement printed `<itertools._grouper object ...>` multiple times, it means the loop is working as expected for a number of iterations, before reaching the error `too many values to unpack`. This makes me think that `L1` is not of a uniform shape. At least one of its rows might have more than 4 elements. The last print statement before the error would be most helpful. Does it show more than 4 elements?

Comment: @unutbu: this is what the error looks like: "<itertools._grouper object at 0x1c60e50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 127, in <module>
    for X, Y, date, ID in group:
ValueError: too many values to unpack".  All of the entries are 4 elements long, because and earlier portion of my program makes sure of that

Comment: @marsx: I've modified the code in my post (above) to include a debugging print statement. Could you post what the output from the print statement looks like?

Comment: @marsx: Or, if that doesn't help, could you post the actual code you are running (or a relevant snippet) so we have more context?

Comment: @unutbu: your change prints the first entry in my list, containing all 4 elements (April, John Smith, 2009-06-23, 1954), then this error: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 129, in <module>
    X,Y,date,ID = elt
ValueError: too many values to unpack".  does it make a difference that `Y` is multiple words or that `date` is a datetime object?

Comment: @unutbu: L1 is a list of strings, made using the code `L1.append('%s, %s, %s, %s' %(X, Y, date, ID))`

Comment: @marsx: Ahh!! That's the problem! `L1` is a list of `N` strings. In my code I was assuming `L1` is a list of `N` 4-tuples. I need to leave right now; I will update my code when I get back.

Comment: @marsx: I've edited the code to (hopefully) work with `L1` being a list of strings. There is a lot more ugly boiler-plate code needed when `L1` is a list of strings. If `L1` were constructed with `L1.append((X, Y, date, ID))` then a lot of subsequent code could be made simpler. You might want to consider doing that instead.

Comment: @unutbu: Thank you for helping me so much! I just tried the code and its telling me the `else:` is invalid syntax? I'm sorry to keep bugging you with this

Comment: @marsx: Try removing the `else:` block entirely. Since we are just trying to `continue` here, we could just as well not use the `else`. Perhaps you are using an older version of Python which does not define the `else:` syntax?

Comment: @unutbu: thanks, I think there is something else wrong in my code, its telling me there is a syntax error on line 135 but my code is only 134 lines.  do you know how to fix that? i tried just going down a line and deleting but that didnt work

Comment: @marsx: Hmm... Make sure all your parentheses and multi-line strings (`'''`) are paired (closed). Those are the only ways I can think of that might produce the SyntaxError you describe.

Comment: @marsx: An open bracket (`[`) or brace (`{`) could also cause this.

Comment: @marsx: Also, as a general debugging technique, if you progressively remove blocks of code, you can eventually find the trouble-maker.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like

```
L2 = []
for xy,rem in itertools.groupby(L1, lambda x: x.split(",", 2)[:2]):
    for s in rem:
        date,id = s.split(",")
        if TEST_ID(id):
            L2.append(s)
            break
```